# Why does my SSH passphrase work with `plink` and not `ssh`?

Tags: linux, ssh, putty

I've configured my router to accept a public key SSH session with a passphrase.  They key pair was generated using the PuTTY tools on windows.

I can open the session from both Windows and Linux using the Putty tools, but I can't do so with `ssh` on Linux.

When prompted by `ssh` for the keyfile's passphrase, it fails.  Ex:

```
~$ ssh root@my.domain.com -p 123 -i ./key-ddwrt.ppk
DD-WRT v24-sp2 micro (c) 2010 NewMedia-NET GmbH
Release: 06/09/10 (SVN revision: 14583)
Enter passphrase for key './key-ddwrt.ppk':  <*******>
Enter passphrase for key './key-ddwrt.ppk':  <*******>
Enter passphrase for key './key-ddwrt.ppk':  <*******>
```

But using `plink` works:

```
~$ plink -P 48884 -ssh -l root -i ./key-ddwrt.ppk my.domain.com
Using username "root".
DD-WRT v24-sp2 micro (c) 2010 NewMedia-NET GmbH
Release: 06/09/10 (SVN revision: 14583)
Passphrase for key "Hint phrase to jog my memory":  <*******>

Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

root@DD-WRT:~#
```

Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenSSH and the Putty derived tools use a different format for the keys.  If you open up [Puttygen](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter8.html#pubkey) you will be able to [export a key](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter8.html#S8.2.12) that is openssh compatible for authentication.

Comment: putty: mega-irritating. So irritating that I always prefer using the OpenSSH in Cygwin whenever possible.

Answer (score 2):

ppk is a putty-proprietary way of storing the key.  You need to export it as an pem for openssh to make use of it.