# SSH: connect with public key avoiding passphrase prompt

Tags: ssh, tar, files

```
root@myhost:/# ssh -i /opt/id_rsa.pub azureuser@myhost2.cloudapp.net
Enter passphrase for key '/opt/id_rsa.pub':
azureuser@myhost2.cloudapp.net's password:
```

I have created key pair without passphrase, is it possible to get rid of passphrase prompt while connecting to remote server?

I would like to use key connection while using this command:

```
tar -c /opt/lampp/htdocs/somehost | ssh -i /opt/id_rsa.pub azureuser@myhost2.cloudapp.net 'tar -xvf - -C /opt/somefolder' > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

So that files transfer continue even if terminal have lost connection.

Comment: See: http://serverfault.com/questions/182322/why-does-my-ssh-passphrase-work-with-plink-and-not-ssh/182324#182324

Comment: Based on your output the passphrase is being ignored and is falling back to password authentication. It looks like there is a problem with your converted key if you believe it to have no passphrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove (or change) the passphrase using the `-p` option to `ssh-keygen`. For example:

```
ssh-keygen -f /opt/id_rsa -p
```

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the new passphrase prompt to remove the passphrase.

Comment: I haven't passphrase in the first place. Like i said, i have used windows putty keygen and generated keys without passphrase.

Comment: After ssh-keygen -f /opt/id_rsa.pub -p i'm getting this:
Enter old passphrase:
Bad passphrase.

Comment: Then you need to enter the _correct_ passphrase, or use some utility which generates correct keys (like `ssh-keygen`).

Comment: The fact is, that i use these keys to connect via putty and it doesn't ask me for passphrase...

Comment: @Somebody how did you convert the keys from putty's format to ssh's format?

Comment: Yea i guess i have converted them somehow. I don't remember already...