# autossh -> private key without passphrase

Tags: mysql, ssh, debian, tunnel

I would like to tunnel a mysql database. So I thought I use a private key without a passphrase to make it reboot friendly. The problem is, openssh still asks me for a passphrase and if I leave it empty it denies the connection. Is there a way to disable the passphrase question and allow a connection without a password ?

```
/usr/bin/autossh -M 20009 -N -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 -p 22 -i /home/tunnel-vserver_main-mysql/keys/tunnel_mysql ssh-tunnel@IP
```

---

tunnel_mysql looks like this, is that wrong ?:

```
I deleted a bit and it is still a trash key.
PuTTY-User-Key-File-2: ssh-rsa
Encryption: none
Comment: rsa-key-20130902
Public-Lines: 4
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAIBSeG8XkgFsq3TK8MQm9+8Uk+waP0k/xfySbE2Q
ktBsaG/XQd6MskhPjPr*****j5p0VcfWfkpopVB/s
iA1WNJl4Tw/ELxRe6s8XJaz+G2L6K4nCZK/rTdAus4MuwAwWFUmteU7P/Okb6jQ3
SNWPVQ==
Private-Lines: 8
AAAAgDwuXuevu9mtjJQXemGgKwEtrEqBNXO5/X+bI9gzyIZ1uWW6cff3uDoM7mZQ
kznCzjZmvK2l7DhVlHeO2hUKXdldzAIIZmILiIuQb819Hupb4jxApk7zwQREYqW2
a8+pz5LdtGHt****AGaEB+cbCULCeHrzJPP9BY
sWigPwjI47vbAAAAQQCFLH7cXVEiNzmHZyX6XE2Gu++t4LvIVtegBb8koKOzOM9O
6EGDP7I+V4nQI+L6ykKIL6S4pNJp9UaHCKGLwOCPAAAAQHE50FWzp1uB9KJ4qYJe
NS4pLSC88KOYJyT6W66Z1nCLeAL9VG2v1vOZoDsuXDUroVj4uEjq0wmdmif2fOMH
HoM=
Private-MAC: ***
```

Comment: Are you sure the key is in the correct format?  What do you see what you do a `head -3 /home/tunnel-vserver_main-mysql/keys/tunnel_mysql`?  Does it say `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`, or something else?  Do you see lines like `Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED`, `DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC`?

Comment: edited top post, too long for comment

Comment: Well there is your problem.  You are trying to use a Putty key with OpenSSH.  The formats are not compatible.  Use the Putty Key gen tool's function that permits you to export an OpenSSH key. See: http://serverfault.com/a/182324/984

Comment: found it thanks. If you create this as answer I mark it as done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use normal ssh for that:

```
ssh -f ssh-tunnel@IP -L 3307:localhost:3306 -N
```

Just ensure that the key is in the .ssh/id_rsa for that account and that it is also in the .ssh/authorized_users file on the remote end.

Comment: it still ask for a passphrase and deny the entry if I leave it blank.

Comment: The connection via. Putty is working with this key.

Comment: @Aaron Mason. I have the same problem. When running autossh as sudo or root the system keeps asking me for the passphrase.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Stunnel would be appropriate here?

https://www.stunnel.org/index.html

Comment: It might be helpful to expand your answer and describe what you're linking to, and why it's appropriate.